# Using AJAX request with CodeIgniter forms

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, validation

I am having trouble in combining CodeIgniter and AJAX. I have a sign up form. What I want is that when user clicks on sign up button on my home page, he gets a sign up form in pop up. If he enter wrong details in the form , he is prompted on the pop up itself that your details are invalid, He must not be redirected to new page to show errors. So I am using bpopup to make my form pop up and ajax request, but I am not able to perform form_validation, I am little confused. If user does not pass form validation a HTML document is alerted to the user because of view being loaded. If I will not load the view , it will not show login page. If I will directly load view , how will I show user individual errors , like password must be 6 characters long. Here is my code :

My login view :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sign In</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
     var frm = $('form');
     frm.submit(function () {
     $("#status").empty();
     $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == "invalid") {
              $('#status').html("Invalid Login Details");
            }
            else if(data == "valid")
            {
                $('#status').html("Login successful");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    location.reload();
                },600);
            }
            else
            {
                $('#status').html("Your Account is not Activated");
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="Header">
    <h3>Sign In </h3>
</div>
<div id="status"></div>
<div class="main">
    <?php echo form_open('xyz/signin'); //Renders the form element and adds extra functionality like Adds a hidden CSFR prevention field.?> 
    <h5>Email</h5>  // For the time being I have remove echo form_error.
    <input type="text" name="email"  value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" size="25"/>
    <h5>Password *</h5> // For the time being I have remove echo form_error.
    <input type="password" name="password" size="25"/>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" "/></div>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my sign in function of xyz controller :

```
public function signin()
{
  $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $config = array(
array(
'field' => 'email',
'label' => 'Email Address',
'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean'
),
array(
'field' => 'password',
'label' => 'Password',
'rules' => 'trim|required|xss_clean'
)
  );
  $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)  /
{
    $this->load->view('pinflag/login.php');
}
else                               //format of form is correct
{   
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
    $data = array(
        'email' => $email,
        'password' => $password
        );
    $result = $this->user_model->get_users($data);
    if($result->num_rows == 1)   //login details are correct
    {
        $result = $result->result_array();
        if($result[0]['status'] == 0)
        {
            echo "notActivated";

        }
        else
        {
        $this->session->set_userdata('id',$result[0]['id']);
        $this->session->set_userdata('name',$result[0]['fname']);
            echo "valid";
        }
            }
            else        //when user enter invalid login details
    {
        echo "invalid";
    }

}
}
```

Sorry, indentation got all messed up when I pasted the code here.

Comment: I just need help that how should I process all my request on pop up along side using CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't get how your pop is coming but for error and success messages try

```
$this->session->set_flashdata("msg","<span class='m_error'>".$this->lang->line('global_insert_error')."</span>");
```

before your page to be loaded.

and inside your login view any part

```
if($this->session->flashdata('msg'))
{
   echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');
}
```

Comment: I have a sign in function in controller which loads login view. Now my problem is , if I load this->load->view('login') , then each time user click on submit. It will again load the view. How to void this problem ? I just want that my sign in page load once, and then make AJAX request to check login details. Shall I make seperate functions , one to show view and other to check details ? For pop up i have used bpopup, it just loads the url you provide in a pop up window

Comment: check if the login was success redirect to another page.